# Why I don't get the right result

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I want to add two 30 digit numbers with assembly. As you know in 8086 we can not add two number with 30 digits. So I have to do it with string. And use of AAA command and put the result in sum variable and finally check neither we have carry out or not but the main problem is the result of the sum is not correct. It is giving me 59427532 with sum of this 668399 + 759133.

Could you tell me where is the exact problem?

```
    .model small
    .stack 64
    .data
    max1 db 30  
    acc1 db ?
    num1 db 30 dup('0')
    max2 db 30
    acc2 db ?
     num2 db 30
    sum db 31 dup('0'),'$'
    .code 
    start:
     mov ax,@data
     mov ds, Ax
     mov ah,0ah
     lea dx, max1   ;take max 1 and length store it to acc1
     int 21h 
     mov ah,0ah
     lea dx,max2    ;take max2 and length store it to acc2
     int 21h
       mov cl,acc1  ;check if they are equal
     cmp cl,acc2
     jne exit
     mov ch,0   ;make sure our cx is the length of our string
     clc
      mov si,cx ;set the length for index the char
      dec si        
      l1:
      mov al,num1[si]   ;sum two hex number
      adc al,num2[si]   ;add with carry flag
       aaa          ;seperate carry and  hex number and store it into al
       pushf    
       add al,30h       ;convert it to ascii again
       mov sum[si+2],al ;because of dec si we have to step
       popf
       dec si
       loop l1
       jne print
        mov sum,31h     ; if we have carry flag add to sum otherwise jumpt print 
       print:
       mov ah,09h       ;the main problem is here shows the result
       lea dx,sum
        int 21h                      
       exit:
      mov ax,4c00h
       int 21h
     end start
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you my friend for your help i found the problem. we should have to replace 
mov sum[si+1], al
instead of 
mov sum[si+2],al

Comment: When your question is sufficiently answered, you should accept the best answer given on site, even if it is your own! (That will give you a badge)